# Android handle soft enter key

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I'm building a very simple list app on android where I have an edittext for input, a listview to store saved input, and a button to push text from the edittext to listview. Right now I am trying to handle the error key, so not only does it not create a new line on press, but also so that it will send the text to the listview when I click the enter button.

I set the edittext to singleline to prevent new lines, and I added an onEditorActionListener to my edittext to handle the keyevents. Here's my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch|actionGo"
    android:hint="Enter a new item"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myImageButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/myImageButton"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Declare our View variables
private ListView mListView;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mDoneButton;
private ImageButton mImageButton;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Assign the view from the layout file to the corresponding variables
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    mDoneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myDoneButton);
    mImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myImageButton);


    // Listview items adapter
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    readItems();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    mListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    //setup enter listener
    mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                //handle search key click
                onAddItem(v);
                Log.d(TAG, "Handled!");
                return true;
            }
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                //Handle go key click
                onAddItem(v);
                return true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
}

//Add item to list from either the button or enter
public void onAddItem(View v) {
    String itemText = mEditText.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(itemText);
    mEditText.setText("");

    writeItems();
}
```

The code giving me trouble. I'm not even getting anything back from that log.d, but everything else in the code, except for this listener, works as expected.

```
        //setup enter listener
    mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                //handle search key click
                onAddItem(v);
                Log.d(TAG, "Handled!");
                return true;
            }
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                //Handle go key click
                onAddItem(v);
                return true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `IME_ACTION_SEARCH` and others you need to specify these actions in your xml-layout as well:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch|others"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Dang, the tutorial I was following didn't mention that at all! I am, however, still having the same issue. I've updated my code above with the imeOptions.

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong imeOptions? The tutorial I was following was moreso for a browser app.